# bool value always returns true flutter

Tags: flutter, boolean

I am having trouble with the bool value. My bool value returns true only.
I have five buttons which set the state for the bool and time for fasting.

```
 ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
                          playLocalAsset(0);
                          if((isFasting = true) && (widget.isFasting = true)) {
                            showError();
                            removeHours(fastDurs);
                            setState(() {
                              isFasting = false;
                              widget.isFasting = false;
                            });
                            //showAlerts();
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              isFasting = true;
                              widget.isFasting = true;
                              fastDuration = 16;
                              sixteen = 16;
                              eighteen = null;
                              twenty= null;
                              twentytwo = null;
                              twentyfour = null;
                              widget.fastDuration= 16;
                              endTime = startTime.add(Duration(hours: fastDuration!));
                              endTimeS = DateFormat('y/M/d, hh:mma').format(endTime);
                              _textLine = prefs
                                  .setString('formattedDate', endTimeS)
                                  .then((value) => (prefs
                                  .getString('formattedDate') ??
                                  Languages.of(context)!.setYourFastTime +'\n'+ startTimeS));

                              textDate = prefs.setString('eatTime', Languages.of(context)!.youWillEatAt)
                                  .then((value) => (prefs.getString('eatTime') ?? ''));
                              showMessage(Languages.of(context)!.yourFastTimeIsSet);
                              updateHours(16);
                            });
                          }
                          },
                        child: Text('16:8', style: Constants.textTitleStyle),
                        style: Constants.buttonStyle),
                    const SizedBox(width:170),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
                          playLocalAsset(0);
                          if ((isFasting = true) && (widget.isFasting = true)) {
                            showError();
                            removeHours(fastDurs);
                            setState(() {
                              isFasting = false;
                              widget.isFasting = false;
                            });
                            //showAlerts();
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              isFasting = true;
                              widget.isFasting = true;
                              fastDuration = 18;
                              eighteen = 18;
                              sixteen = null;
                              twenty= null;
                              twentytwo = null;
                              twentyfour = null;
    widget.fastDuration = 18;
    endTime = startTime.add(Duration(hours: fastDuration!));
    endTimeS = DateFormat('y/M/d, hh:mma').format(endTime);
    _textLine = prefs
        .setString('formattedDate', endTimeS)
        .then((value) =>
    (prefs
        .getString('formattedDate') ??
        Languages.of(context)!.setYourFastTime + '\n' + startTimeS));
    textDate =
        prefs.setString('eatTime', Languages.of(context)!.youWillEatAt)
            .then((value) => (prefs.getString('eatTime') ?? ''));
    showMessage(Languages.of(context)!.yourFastTimeIsSet);
    updateHours(18);
  });
                          }
                          showNotificationOneTime(context,
                              startTime.add(const Duration(hours: 14)).hour,
                              startTime.add(const Duration(minutes: 0)).minute);
                          showNotif(context,
                              endTime.hour, endTime.minute);},
                        child: Text('18:6', style: Constants.textTitleStyle), 
                        style: Constants.buttonStyle
                    ),
```

i declare my isFasting bool as nullable, then in init I check for the time, and if it is before the endTime then bool isFasting = true. As such:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

String startTimeS = DateFormat('y/M/d, hh:mma').format(startTime);
String endTimeS = DateFormat('y/M/d, hh:mma').format(endTime);

_textLine = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
  String? fastEndTime = prefs.getString('formattedDate');
  if ((fastEndTime != null) && (endTime
          .isAfter(DateFormat('y/M/d, hh:mma').parse(fastEndTime)))) {
    setState(() {
      isFasting = false;
      widget.isFasting = false;
    });
    return Languages.of(context)!.yourFastTimeFinished +"\n"+ endTimeS;
  }
  if (isFasting = false) {
    return Languages.of(context)!.setYourFastTime +"\n"+ startTimeS;
  }
  if ((fastEndTime != null) && (endTime
      .isBefore(DateFormat('y/M/d, hh:mma').parse(fastEndTime)))){
    setState(() {
      isFasting = true;
      widget.isFasting = true;
    });
  }
    return fastEndTime ??
        Languages.of(context)!.setYourFastTime + "\n" + startTimeS;
});

textDate = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
  String? stillFastingTime = prefs.getString('eatTime');
  String? fastEndTime = prefs.getString('formattedDate');
  if ((fastEndTime != null) && (endTime
      .isBefore(DateFormat('y/M/d, hh:mma').parse(fastEndTime)))) {
    setState(() {
      isFasting = true;
      widget.isFasting = true;
    });
    return Languages.of(context)!.youWillEatAt;
  }
  return stillFastingTime ?? '';
});
}
```

so, if isFasting is true then fast is cancelled and isFasting set to false. then clicking on a diff button should set state as shown in else condition. However, my isFasting is always true. it does not turn off... And it does not remove the previous hours, and it does not change the string of the text according to state. How do I make that bool value work properly? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `==` instead of `=` when checking for equality:

`if (isFasting = false)` to `if (isFasting == false)`

and

`if((isFasting = true) && (widget.isFasting = true))` to `if(isFasting == true && widget.isFasting == true)` also the braces here can be removed.

`!=` is correct here

Comment: oh my goood lol such a small thing, big difference! so setting with = , and checking with == ? how come i completely missed that!? thanks!

Comment: Happens to everyone at some point :D

setting with `=` and checking with `==` and `!=`